# MySQL - JOIN or INSERT QUERY RESULTS

Tags: jquery, mysql, database, insert, join

I want to be able to combine two query results into a Single table or Single Query Result. I am combining tables on woocommerce.

The **first query** result contains the sales order and the shipping details:

SELECT bso.ID AS order_item_id, bsd.NAME AS order_item_name, 'shipping' AS order_item_type, bso.ID AS order_id
FROM bso
LEFT OUTER JOIN bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID
WHERE bso.ID IN (255, 810)

The **second query** contains the ordered items with the **order_id** as a link:

SELECT bsb.ID AS order_item_id, bsb.NAME AS order_item_name, 'line_item' AS order_item_type, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_id 
FROM b_sale_basket bsb
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID IN (810, 255)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/auFXa.png

I must combine the two query results and should look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Td6o.png

Please guide me on how to do this. Thanks for any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello there.. Thanks for the welcome. I am still finding ways how to do it. Do you have any idea how to implement the final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to combine the two results you could try using `UNION`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Your query would end up looking something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT bso.ID AS order_item_id, bsd.NAME AS order_item_name, 'shipping' AS order_item_type, bso.ID AS order_id FROM bso LEFT OUTER JOIN bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID WHERE bso.ID IN (255, 810)
UNION
SELECT bsb.ID AS order_item_id, bsb.NAME AS order_item_name, 'line_item' AS order_item_type, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_id FROM b_sale_basket bsb WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID IN (810, 255)
) aux ORDER BY order_id;
```

Comment: Hello Santiago, Thanks for the response. as you can see on this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/auFXa.png -- this has two tables and the result must look like http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Td6o.png .. do you think UNION is able to achieve the end result?

Comment: Hi @Redshot, UNION should combine both results and order them by the "order_id" column, but the order_item_id column would not look as the one you indicated in the picture since this column shows info that comes directly from the tables.. Welcome to StackOverflow btw!

Comment: Hi Santiago, Thank you for the info. I am able to see results because of you. Thank you bro.

Comment: Thanks bro. I have ticked the check to green.